# Equivalent metric spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I really can't even the question . Are there any ideas .
İf d1 and d2 are metrics on the same set X and there are positive numbers a and b such that for all $
{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}\mathrm{\in}{X}
$

$
{ad}{1}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{d}{2}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{bd}{1}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}
$

Show that the cauchy sequences in (X,d1) and ( X,d2) are the same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $(X,d_1)$. Then for $e>0$, there is $N>0$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, we have
$$
d_1(x_n,x_m)<\frac{e}{b}.
$$
Then for all such $m,n$, $d_2(x_n,x_m)<bd_1(x_n,x_m)=b\frac{e}{b}=e$.

Similarly, form the reverse direction based on the following observation:
$$
d_2(x_n,x_m)<ae\implies d_1(x_n,x_m)<\frac{1}{a}d_2(x_n,x_m)=\frac{1}{a}ae=e.
$$

Comment: Sir, what is general criterion to show two Cauchy sequences are same?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You have to show 2 things as in the answer: show that Cauchy under $d_1$ implies Cauchy under $d_2$ and show that Cauchy under $d_2$ implies Cauchy under $d_1$. Essentially, whenever you have to demonstrate that 2 sets are the same, it is enough to show that a membership of one set implies a membership of the other set. Since there are 2 sets, there are 2 demonstrations.